# Which databases support encryption

Tags: windows, database-recommendation, mariadb, encryption

I'm searching for a database that can run on Windows and can be accessed with C#.
The Database also requires that the data can be encrypted (ideally without backdoors).

Can MariaDB serve here?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL comes to my mind. You have pgcrypto library for encrpyting data and there are drivers for .Net

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does encryption. Just research Transparent Data Encryption.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above MS-SQL server suits you're requirement:

On how to proceed with MS SQL databases refer to below article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

For data encryption, yes its possible depending upon the edition you are going to use:

refer to this for further read on encryption via sql server : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Without being to paranoid the "ideally without backdoors" cannot be ensured as MS might be force with US law to build some in without telling anybody. Might underlined five times.